# Running "docker-compose run --rm composer update" not working in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: laravel, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, composer-php

I have a Jenkins pipeline just for learning purposes, which should build a Laravel app via docker-compose. The "docker-compose --build" step is working fine, but next it is running "docker-compose run --rm composer update", which then stops, no error or output.
When I run the command manually after accessing the server via SSH, the command runs with no issues.

Composer service in docker-compose file:

```
composer:
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
container_name: composer
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html
working_dir: /var/www/html
depends_on:
  - php
user: laravel
entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
networks:
  - laravel
```

Build step in jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Build') {
     steps {
         echo 'Building..'
         sh 'chmod +x scripts/jenkins-build.sh'
         sh './scripts/jenkins-build.sh'
     }
 }
```

Command in shell script:

```
print "Building docker app"
sudo docker-compose up -d --build site # works fine
sudo chown jenkins -R ./

print "Running composer"
sudo docker-compose run --rm composer update # hangs in jenkins but works in cmd?
```

View in Jenkins:

[image]

Same command working on same server, via cmd:
[image]

I know there are some bad practices in here, but this is just for learning purposes. Jenkins server is running Ubuntu 20.04 on AWS EC2 instance.

Comment: Is there any good reason to do this? Usually, you should run `composer update`  during development, put `composer.lock`  under version control, use `composer install`  afterwards

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, thanks for that info, I wasn't aware that is the way you would normally manage this. However, I have the same issue running composer install anyway, so I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to installing composer directly into my PHP docker image. Therefore instead of running the composer service, I now use `docker exec php composer update`.
From what I can see, any services that were used via `docker-compose run` did not work in the Jenkins pipeline. In my case, these were all services that were only running whilst performing some action (like `composer update`), so maybe that is why Jenkins did not like it.